# Summation Notation with Subscripts on the sigma

Tags: measure-theory, notation

I'm reading a book on machine learning and on the topic of dot product calculations, it presents the notation for the formulaic process as the following.

Another way to calculate the dot product is:

$\textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{v} = \sum_i{\textbf{u}_i \times \textbf{v}_i}$

I'm unclear with this use of sigma notation. What does this mean with a "standard" notation as would be taught in Algebra II.

I.E. $\sum_{i=S}^L$ whereas L is the upper bound and S is the starting point.

Comment: There is no upper limit on the sigma sign to generalise for 2d 3d or higher vectors. The context of the problem usually makes that obvious.

Comment: It usually means just sum over all indices $i$. There are many subtle variants of sum notation...